# Query db dynamically using HTML form as scheme

Tags: php, mysql, forms, selection

I am a beginner with php.
I have a data table something like this

```
| serial    | | name            | | email           | | phone       | | location    | | profession  | | source  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1         | | Mr first        | | a@example.com   | | 123456780   | | India       | | Designer    | | From X  |
| 2         | | Mr second       | | b@example.com   | | 123456781   | | US          | | Designer    | | From Y  |
| 3         | | Mr third        | | c@example.com   | | 123456782   | | US          | | Engineer    | | From X  |
| 4         | | Mr fourth       | | d@example.com   | | 123456783   | | US          | | Disigner    | | From Z  |
| 5         | | Mr fifth        | | e@example.com   | | 123456784   | | India       | | Engineer    | | From Y  |
| 6         | | Mr sixth        | | f@example.com   | | 123456785   | | UK          | | Designer    | | From X  |
| 7         | | Mr seventh      | | g@example.com   | | 123456786   | | India       | | Designer    | | From X  |
```

I have a html form like this

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
 <select name="location">
 <option value="" selected="selected">-any-</option>
 <option value="UK">UK</option>
 <option value="India">India</option>
 <option value="US">US</option>
 </select>

 <select name="source">
 <option value="" selected="selected">-any-</option>
 <option value="From X">From X</option>
 <option value="From Y">From Y</option>
 <option value="From Z">From Z</option>
 </select>

 <select name="profession">
 <option value="" selected="selected">-any-</option>
 <option value="Designer">Designer</option>
 <option value="Engineer">Engineer</option>
    </select>
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Now i want the query based on multiple selection

1. If "any-" is selected in all three drop downs it should fetch all table rows
2. If any two items selected i.e, location=india and profession=designer, then it should fetch only 1st and 7th row where both the select values are matching

Please help me with the php to fetch the results based on form select values

Here is my php to retrieve post values

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("alldata");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$source=$_POST['source'];
$profession=$_POST['profession'];
$location=$_POST['location'];
}

?>
```

my php file now looks like

```
    <?php 
$conn = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error()); 
$selected = mysql_select_db ("alldata") 
or die ("Could not select database because: " . mysql_error()); 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$source=$_POST['source'];
$profession=$_POST['profession'];
$location=$_POST['location'];
}
$where = '';
if(isset($location) && !empty($location)){
    $where .= "location ='$location' AND ";
}
if(isset($profession) && !empty($profession)){
     $where .= "profession ='$profession' AND ";
}
if(isset($source) && !empty($source)){
        $where .= "source ='$source' AND ";
}
$where = substr($where, 0, (strlen($where) - 4));
$where = ($where != '') ? "WHERE $where":'';
$sql= "select * from data $where";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn)or die (mysql_error()); 
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0){ 
echo "No Match Found"; 
}else{ 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
echo "" .$row['name']." " .$row['email']." ".$row["phone"]." ".$row["source"]." ".$row["profession"]." ".$row["location"]."<br>";

echo "<br>"; 
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------"."<br>"; 
} 
} 
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

its fetching all the rows instead of filtering based on post values. Please help

I tried the below one. I am able to get the result by filtering values. But if there is any empty selection i need to skip that value from filtering. Here is my code

```
$sql = "select * from data
        where location = '".$_POST['location']."' 
        AND profession = '". $_POST['profession'] ."' 
        AND source = '". $_POST['source'] ."'";
```

Comment: You just have to get the data after submit with `$_POST['elementname']` and create your query according to received information. So, what is the question - getting the form data or creating the query?

Comment: I am able to get the data after submit. I need to create a query where i can fetch the results with exact  matching rows. Thanks in advance

Comment: where is ur code for `php` where u handle the `post` request

Comment: the question is really unclear, please explain better what you trying to do

Comment: @sanjeev my answer will help you

Comment: *Text about deprecated mysql_*

Comment: Thanks all. I am trying the answers here. But some how i am getting blank result page.

Comment: hi sanjeev just echo $sql in and run paste query here also run the same query in phpmyadmin and check its return result or not

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
$where = '';
if(isset($location) && !empty($location)){
    $where .= "location ='$location' AND ";
}
if(isset($profession) && !empty($profession)){
     $where .= "profession ='$profession' AND ";
}
if(isset($source) && !empty($source)){
        $where .= "source ='$source' AND ";
}
$where = substr($where, 0, (strlen($where) - 4));
$where = ($where != '') ? "WHERE $where":'';
$sql= "select * from tablename $where";
```

Comment: Hi Praveen, I am still not able to get the results. Please help me. I tried your answer, its fetching all the rows irrespective of selected items

Comment: please print the value of $location,$source,$proffesion it should not be blank.if blank then it will give you all rows else the specific as per your need

Answer (score 0):

```
// get your real values from $_POST array here 
$location   = null; // i.e. "any"
$source     = 'from x';
$profession = 'designer'; 

$filters = array(
    'location'   => $location, 
    'source'     => $source,
    'profession' => $profession,
    // etc
);

$where = 'WHERE';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";

foreach ($filters as $field => $value) {
    if($value) {
        $sql .= " $where $field = '$value'";
        $where = 'AND';
    }
}

$sql .= ";";

echo $sql; // SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE source = 'from x' AND profession = 'designer';
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("alldata");
    $select='SELECT serial,name,email,phone,location,profession,source From <table_name> ';

    $where =' Where 1 ';

    if(isset($_POST['location']) && trim($_POST['location'])!='')
    {
       $where.=' and location= '.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location']);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['source']) && trim($_POST['source'])!='')
    {
       $where.=' and source= '.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['source']);     
    }

    if(isset($_POST['profession']) && trim($_POST['profession'])!='')
    {
       $where.=' and profession= '.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['profession']);   
    }

    $query=$select.$where;
    $request=mysql_query($query) or die('query_error');

    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><td>serial</td><td>name</td><td>email</td><td>phone</td><td>location</td><td>profession</td><td>source</td></tr>";
    while($result=mysql_fecth_array($request))
    {
       echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>".$result['serial']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$result['name']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$result['email']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$result['phone']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$result['location']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$result['profession']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$result['source']."</td>";
       echo "</tr>";


    }
    echo "</table>";
 }

?>

<form method="post" action="search.php">
 <select name="location">
 <option value="" selected="selected">-any-</option>
 <option value="UK">UK</option>
 <option value="India">India</option>
 <option value="US">US</option>
 </select>

 <select name="source">
 <option value="" selected="selected">-any-</option>
 <option value="From X">From X</option>
 <option value="From Y">From Y</option>
 <option value="From Z">From Z</option>
 </select>

 <select name="profession">
 <option value="" selected="selected">-any-</option>
 <option value="Designer">Designer</option>
 <option value="Engineer">Engineer</option>
    </select>
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Suhel, I am getting blank result.. Any idea?

Comment: have u give ur table name in <table_name>

Comment: do one thing ... put a line after `$query=$select.$where;`  `echo $query."<br />;"` and run this query in ur mysql admin to verify the result

Comment: `echo $query."<br />".;`  put query in querybrowser

Comment: in mysql admin i am getting the query results. but in browser i am not

Comment: sorry for mistake... cut and paste all the php code into ur search.php file.... as u r submitting this form on search.php...